# Display list of students in Datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a student class which has all these fields and properties.
**studentId, studentFirstname, studentLastname, test1Score, test2Score, studentMajor, typeOfStudent**.

I computed the student grades and save them in a file. Now i want to display them in a datagridview, but i want to display: **studentId, studentLastname, studentMajor, studentGrade**.

Here's what my code looks like:

After i opened the open diaolg and get the file that i want to display.
The commented lines are the fields that i don't want to display. in my datagridview.

```
 while (sLine != null)
                    {
                        string[] parts = sLine.Split(seps);


                        StudentGrade st = new StudentGrade();
                        st.Id = int.Parse(parts[0]);
                        //st.FirstName = parts[1];
                        st.LastName = parts[1];
                        // st.Test1 = int.Parse(parts[3]);
                        // st.Test2 = int.Parse(parts[4]);
                        st.Major = parts[2];
                        // st.TypeOfStudent = parts[6];
                        st.Grade = parts[3];

                        STList.Add(st);

                        sLine = sstr.ReadLine();
                        if (sLine == null)
                            break;
                        if (sLine.Trim() == "")
                            break;
                    }

                    dgStudents.DataSource = STList;
                    dgStudents.Refresh();

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Visible property of unwanted columns to false...

```
dgStudents.Columns["FirstName"].Visible = false;
dgStudents.Columns["Test1"].Visible = false;
dgStudents.Columns["Test2"].Visible = false;
dgStudents.Columns["TypeOfStudent"].Visible = false;
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Is there another way of doing that using a foreach loop?

Comment: Ricky, do you mean foreach loop for hiding of columns? If yes, you can define list of columns `var columnsToHide = new List<string>() { "FirstName", "Test1", "Test2", "TypeOfStudent" };` and then hide in loop:
`columnsToHide.ForEach(x => dgStudents.Columns[x].Visible = false );`.

Answer (score 0):

You can select required columns as below to fill the `datagridview`.

```
dgStudents.DataSource = STList.Select(col => new StudentGrade
{
    Id = col.Id,
    LastName = col.LastName,
    Major = col.Major,
    Grade = col.Grade
}.ToList();
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Is there another way of doing that using a foreach loop?